# Как развернуть Java web приложение на удаленном Wildfly сервере?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, сервер, развертывание, wildfly

Как развернуть Java web приложение на удаленном Wildfly сервере?
На  localhost приложение отлично работает.

Итак у меня есть доменное имя mysite.com которое адресует на мой vps сервер. Java уже установлена  и запущен wildfly .  В директорию deployments  поместил "mysite.com.war" и запустил wildfly с помощью команды ./standalone.sh -Djboss.http.port=80. Но в браузере сайт mysite.com не доступен. Хорошая новость -  mysite.com:8080 отображает стандартную заставку   wildfly, то есть я уже близок и сервер запущен и доменное имя адресует верно. На хосте не установлен ни  apache ни  nginx, только  wildfly.  Что мне сделать, чтоб по адресу  http:// mysite.com запускалось мое приложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, что запускается оно у вас в standalone-режиме. Тогда находите standalone.xml и в секции подсистемы undertow прописываете соответствие домена приложению:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
        <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </host>
        <host name="some-host" alias="example.com,site1.example.com" default-web-module="some-app" disable-console-redirect="false"/>
        <host name="another-host" alias="site2.example.com" default-web-module="another-app" disable-console-redirect="false"/>
    </server>
    ...
</subsystem>
```

Потом в этом же файле находите секцию интерфейсов и исправляете 127.0.0.1 на ваш ip-адрес:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:151.101.65.69}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Наконец следом должна идти секция `socket-binding-group` в которой можно исправить используемые порты:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    ...
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:80}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:443}"/>
    ...
</socket-binding-group>
```

Либо, на том же сервере можно развернуть Nginx и настроить проксирование запросов с внешнего ip и порта 80 на 127.0.0.1:8080.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что я искал! Работает :)
Уточнения:
1) standalone-режим нужен тогда, когда твое приложение запущено на одном экземпляре wildfly?
2)Nginx нужен тогда, когда твое приложение будет запущено на нескольких экземплярах wildfly, выступая в роли распределителя нагрузки? А при одном экземпляре wildfly, установка nginx бессмысленна?

Comment: 3)Приложение теперь работает отлично, теперь для старта wildfly из консоли, достаточно выполнить команду "./standalone.sh", это же удаленный сервер и я это делаю это по ssh, когда я закрываю окно терминала, wildfly на удаленном сервере вырубается)) Как мне запустить wildfly перманентно? или в автозагрузку поставить что ли? Какая правильная практика?

Comment: 1. Да, доменный режим для кластера. 2. Обычно Nginx перед Wildfly не нужен. Я бы стал его использовать, если бы мне на этом же сервере надо было раздавать сайты на других технологиях. 3. Это зависит от операционной системы вашего сервера. Почитайте про SysV, Upstart и Systemd.

Answer (score 0):

Игра с интерфейсами и портами у меня не вышла.   Поэтому был выполнен редирект портов силами firewalld (файерволла RedHat) по схеме: external_ip:80 <> 127.0.0.1:8080 , external_ip:443 <> 127.0.0.1:8443.
2) Nginx - так же можно использовать для дополнительных функций или сайтов с разными технологиями либо как балансировщик, когда есть кластер WildFly;
3) Необходимо описать и создать сервис wildfly для systemd, после тестирования прописать его в автозагрузку.
Вот содержание моего /etc/systemd/system/wildfly.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=The WildFly Application Server
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User=wildfly
Group=wildfly
LimitNOFILE=102642

Environment="WILDFLY_HOME=/opt/wildfly"
Environment="WILDFLY_CONFIG=standalone.xml"
Environment="WILDFLY_BIND=0.0.0.0"
Environment=LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1

PIDFile=/var/run/wildfly/wildfly.pid
ExecStart=/opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -c ${WILDFLY_CONFIG} -b ${WILDFLY_BIND}
ExecStop=/opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=:shutdown
StandardOutput=null
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```